# Is the likelihood in Bayes’s theorem the same one in maximum likelihood estimation?

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning, bayesian

section 1.5 in the [book](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkbayes/thinkbayes.pdf) Rewrites Bayes’s theorem as

$P(H|D) = \dfrac{P(H)P(D|H)}{P(D)}$

and gives this explanation

> p(D|H) is the probability of the data under the hypothesis, called the
>   likelihood.

is this `likelihood` the same one in [maximum likelihood estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation)?

Comment: Yes. When alternative hypotheses are defined by one or more parameters and in situations where the data evidence is stronger than the prior, then the point in parameter space that maximizes the likelihood is near the point with largest posterior density.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Does "data evidence" mean the $P(D|H)$ part?

Comment: The "information" or "evidence" in the data is characterized by the second derivative of the likelihood function at the point of maximum likelihood. If the prior, P(H), is relatively flat compared to the the likelihood function, then the product of the two (the numerator) will be maximized at about the same location as the likelihood itself.